# How to use spring-data-mongodb to implement complex expressions under $substr in Aggregation.project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongodb query that should be converted to spring-data code.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "partnerid": 1,
      "market": {
        "$toUpper": [
          {
            "$substr": [
              "$pseudocitycode",
              0,
              3
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "office": {
        $toUpper: [
          {
            $substr: [
              "$pseudocitycode",
              {
                $subtract: [
                  {
                    $strLenCP: "$pseudocitycode"
                  },
                  2
                ]
              },
              2
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "partnerid": "$partnerid",
        "market": "$market",
        "office": "$office"
      },
      "clickCount": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I have tried using the following code to get started, but stuck how to get the office value.

```
//ArithmeticOperators.Subtract subtract = ArithmeticOperators.valueOf(StringOperators.valueOf("pseudocitycode").lengthCP()).subtract(2);
StringOperators.Substr market = StringOperators.valueOf("pseudocitycode").substring(0, 3);
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("partnerid")
                    .and(StringOperators.valueOf(market).toUpper()).as("market")
                    .andExpression("{$toUpper:[{$substr:['$pseudocitycode',{$subtract:[{$strLenCP:'$pseudocitycode'},2]},2]}]}").as("office");
```

Can anyone help implement the query code above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is you can parse JSON to Document and provide it to MongoCollection:

```
Document projectStage = Document.parse("{\"$project\":...}"); // your project stage JSON
Document groupStage = Document.parse("{\"$group\":...}"); // your group stage JSON

// pass to MongoCollection
List<Document> stages = List.of(projectStage, groupStage);
MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(stages);
```

---

You can still use the `StringOperators` and `ArithmeticOperators` in `spring-data-mongodb` to build your query.
But since there is no method that can accept `AggregationExpression` as the `start` or `length` in `StringOperators.Substr`, you may need to write your implementation about this.
For example:

```
// similar design to the origin StringOperators.SubStr
public static class NewSubStr implements AggregationExpression {
    private final List<?> value;

    private NewSubStr(List<?> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static NewSubStr valueOf(String fieldReference) {
        return new NewSubStr(Fields.fields(fieldReference).asList());
    }

    private String getMongoMethod() {
        return "$substr";
    }

    public NewSubStr substring(AggregationExpression start) {
        return new NewSubStr(this.append(Arrays.asList(start, -1)));
    }

    private List<Object> append(List value) {
        List<Object> clone = new ArrayList<>(this.value);
        clone.addAll(value);
        return clone;
    }

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document(this.getMongoMethod(), this.unpack(value, context));
    }

    private Object unpack(Object value, AggregationOperationContext context) {
        if (value instanceof AggregationExpression) {
            return ((AggregationExpression)value).toDocument(context);
        } else if (value instanceof Field) {
            return context.getReference((Field)value).toString();
        } else if (value instanceof List) {
            List<Object> sourceList = (List)value;
            List<Object> mappedList = new ArrayList(sourceList.size());
            sourceList.stream().map((item) -> {
                return this.unpack(item, context);
            }).forEach(mappedList::add);
            return mappedList;
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use your new SubStr like:

```
AggregationExpression strLenCP = StringOperators.valueOf("$pseudocitycode").lengthCP();
AggregationExpression subtract = ArithmeticOperators.Subtract.valueOf(strLenCP).subtract(2);
AggregationExpression substr = NewSubStr.valueOf("$pseudocitycode").substring(subtract);
AggregationExpression toUpper = StringOperators.valueOf(substr).toUpper();

ProjectionOperation projection = Aggregation.project().and(toUpper).as("pseudocitycode_upper");

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(projection);
```